# Get and set simulation stop time in SIMULINK?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I need to set simulation stop time into a variable in the same simulation; in a gain block I have a variable `t` that actually is the simulation time and I want it to be set automatically, even I change every time simulation stop time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put these in project `InitFcn` callback;

```
stop_time_as_str = get_param(gcs, 'StopTime');
t= str2double(stop_time_as_str);
```

like this:

Right click on the white spot in project window -> select Model properties -> callbacks -> InitFcn

[image]

Comment: Minor point, but you can remove your first line, and in your second line use `gcs` instead of `current_system`.